# How does the isupper method work here?

Tags: python, string

Why do I get `False` when I do:

```
>>> "123".isupper()
False
```

But `True` when I do:

```
>>> "ABC123".isupper()
True
```

Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes, its documented in the documentation. "Return true if all cased characters [4] in the string are uppercase *and there is at least one cased character*, false otherwise." The emphasis is mine.

Comment: @JamesKPolk it's not documented in http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/isupper.html which is what i found when i Googled "python isupper" (or am i an a**hole for not knowing that the doco is buried in https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: ah, well, even the official documentation sometimes leaves much to be desired, but for this method it seems accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the Python 3.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isupper#str.isupper):

> **`str.isupper()`**
>
> Return true if all cased characters [[4]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isupper#id15) in the string are uppercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise.

Since digits are not *cased characters*, there is not at least one cased character thus it returns false. In the second example, there is at least one cased character and they are all uppercase, thus it is true.